# iOS XCode - Swift class not found when building for Profile

Tags: ios, swift, crash, profiling, xcode9.2

Hoping for a quick resolution to this as we have a planned Appstore release this weekend!

In order to debug a crash, I am trying to Profile our iOS/Swift App (Product Menu --> Profile) but I get a Build failure with the following message:

[image]

The App builds perfectly fine when I do the regular Product/Build.

Appreciate any help/insights in resolving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try checking the logs by clicking the **Show the Log Navigator** tab.
- Try restarting XCode or even the entire computer. (sometimes it actually helps)
- Try creating a new sample project to test the problem and see if it reproducible.